# How to call a particular function from the python file through the terminal or a shell script and pass arguments to that function?

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have three functions in a python file. I want to call a particular function from the python file through a shell script or through the terminal and pass an argument to that python function. Is there any way I can do that?

I tried `python -c "exec(open(filename.py).read()); functionName()"` but I don't know how to pass an argument.

How to run,
    `python -c "import a, sys; a.functionName(sys.argv[1])" "sampleString"`
from a shell script?

```
#!/bin/bash

import os

def abracadabra_personal(project):
    directory = "/srv/http/Personal/" + project
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)
    except OSError:
        print("Error! Couldn't create project folder : " + directory)

def sample():
    print("Your argument was got.")
```

The above is my python code. And below is my shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# creates a personal project
function abracadabra_personal() {
    cd
    # python -c "import abracadabra, sys; abracadabra.sample(sys.argv[1])" $1
    python -c "print("hi")"
    echo $1
    cd /srv/http/Personal/
}

# creates an office project
function abracadabra_office() {
    cd
    python abracadabra.py $1
    cd /srv/http/Office/
}

# creates a learning project
function abracadabra_learning() {
    cd
    python abracadabra.py $1
    cd /srv/http/Learning/
}

# creates a freelance project
function abracadabra_freelance() {
    cd
    python abracadabra.py $1
    cd /srv/http/Freelance/
}
```

Comment: You can treat the file as a module: `python -c 'import filename;filename.functionName()'`. What would be the argument?

Comment: The argument will be a string.

Answer (score 2):

The command line arguments are available in [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

```
$ cat a.py                                                    
def functionName(arg):
    print('my argument is {}'.format(arg))
$ python -c 'import a, sys; a.functionName(sys.argv[1])' 'hello world'
my argument is hello world
```

Alternatively, put an [entry point](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) in the Python script. Then you can call this Python module directly.

```
$ cat b.py
def functionName(arg):
    print('my argument is {}'.format(arg))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    functionName(sys.argv[1])
$ python -m b 'hello world'
my argument is hello world
```

If you have a shell variable in a shell script, remember to use double quotes around variable expansions.

```sh
argument='hello world'
…
python -m the_python_module "$argument"
```

Comment: ````python -c 'import a, sys; a.functionName(sys.argv[1])' 'hello world'```` this works but when I put it inside a shell script function it returns nothing. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @DeepakSurya This looks right, so if it doesn't work, it must be in some other part of your code. Post [complete code that reproduces the problem](/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi, I've uploaded the whole source code. Could you check it?

Comment: @DeepakSurya Well, what's the problem?

Comment: I want to call that python function from the shell script.